# How to target Clientapp file if its outside currentdirectory ASP.NET CORE WEB API ANGULAR 8

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-3.0, webapi

How do I make my webApi run my client app if the folder is outside the webapi folder ?

**/repos/project/webApplication** is the main folder , inside it has two more.

The webapi vs project **/repos/project/webApplication/webApplication**

The client app **/repos/project/webApplication/clientApp**

My code now :

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "/clientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
```

Comment: try to use ../ to navigate